# How display and edit HTML in iOS

Tags: ios, text, editor, rich-text-editor

With UIWebView, I can display HTML very well. With UITextView, I can edit HTML. With what can I both display and edit HTML?

Is there any open source project or tutorial available?

Answer (score 3):

You can show your html inside a `UIWebView` with a WYSIWYG editor inside.  There are a lot of WYSIWYG editors out there.  I like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) ([demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo)).

See the [Developer Documentation - Integration](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration) for how to set / get the text of the WYSIWYG editor.

## How to Create the WYSIWYG Editor:

- Download the script files and bundle them in your app
- Include the script (from ckeditor website)

> ```
> <head>
> ...
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
> </head>
> ```

- Add text area with your initial text

> ```
> <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">
>         <p>Initial value.</p>
> </textarea>
> ```

- Create editor using javascript

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">   
>      CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
> </script>
> ```

## How to get Text from WYSIWYG Editor

Use the script:

```
var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
```

You can use [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21) method to run javascript code to get / set the html content as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `UITextViewDelegate` method (such as `textViewDidChange:`) and reload the content of the `UITextView`'s `text` property back into the `UIWebView` (using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`)?

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:textView.text baseURL:nil];
}
```

This will allow you to manually amend HTML and see the result.

Answer (score -1):

check this lib which is updated and can be used above ios 11 and written in swift

-AztecEditor
[link](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/AztecEditor-iOS)

-updated version of 
RichEditorView
[link](https://github.com/Andrew-Chen-Wang/RichEditorView)