# Save HTML data in iPad

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ipad

I've searched through the forum and couldn't find a specific answer on my troubles
    so im hoping that a friendly person or persons are willing to help me out, 
    i will send a lot of good karma in your direction. :)

I have `100 HTML forms` which i have to show in my `iPad application` and i am showing it in `UIWebView` and creating `PDF with the help of taking snapshot`.
    But now requirement has been changed i have to edit that saved HTML file.

> How can i save the data entered by user for editing so that i can
>   save the full HTML file with data in Database.

Hopefully some of you are able and willing to help me out.

I will try to answer everything thats unclear.

Comment: may be this link can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840574/how-display-and-edit-html-in-ios

Comment: hi siba, thanks for your quick response,this will work for one text view but i have more than 200 text fields,check box, radio button,pickers so how can i save all the data.

Comment: you can get the whole HTML content and save in database. Go through this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview